# How to group javascript object array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this javascript array of objects for example:

```
[{
    day : "August 30th",
    id: 1,
    message : "lorem ipsum1"
},{
    day : "August 30th",
    id: 2,
    message : "lorem ipsum2"
},{
    day : "August 31th",
    id: 3,
    message : "lorem ipsum3"
}];
```

and I need to group it to be object and look like this:

```
{
    "August 30th": [{
        day : "August 30th",
        id: 1,
        message : "lorem ipsum1"
    },{
        day : "August 30th",
        id: 2,
        message : "lorem ipsum2"
    }],

    "August 31th": [{
        day : "August 31th",
        id: 4,
        message : "lorem ipsum3"
    }]
}
```

What is the best lodash method to do this?

Comment: `_.groupBy(users, 'day')`

Comment: Phylogenesis thanks

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately, this question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate because of some incorrect terminology in the question (you are asking for your input array to be grouped, rather than sorted).

Comment: @Phylogenesis, you may answer that question, if you like.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed above, you can *group* your objects in Lo-dash as follows:

```
_.groupBy(users, 'day');
```